# pivot_table value NaN missing variables

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, missing-data

I have the following df `data`

```
data
     Site Storage Commodity     parameter         value     unit
0     Mid    Pump      Elec    inst-cap-c  0.000000e+00      MWh
1     Mid    Pump      Elec      cap-lo-c  0.000000e+00      MWh
2     Mid    Pump      Elec      cap-up-c  1.500000e+15      MWh
...
16    Mid    Pump      Elec          init  1.000000e+00     None
17    Mid    Pump      Elec     discharge  3.500000e-06     None
18    Mid    Pump      Elec      ep-ratio           NaN     None
```

The only `parameter` which has a value of `NaN` is `ep-ratio`. I apply pandas `pivot_table()` over this df via:

```
data = data.pivot_table(values='value',
                        index=['Site', 'Storage', 'Commodity'],
                        columns='parameter').reset_index()
```

The problem is after I pivot somehow the parameter ep-ratio disappears.

```
data
    Site Storage Commodity  cap-lo-c  ...   inv-cost-p  var-cost-c  var-cost-p  wacc
0    Mid    Pump      Elec       0.0  ...     100000.0         0.0        0.02  0.07

data['ep-ratio']
*** KeyError: 'ep-ratio'

data['cap-lo-c']
0    0.0
```

So I am assuming it is because `ep-ratio` = `NaN`
**How can I fix this? other than changing the value of ep-ratio**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include `dropna=False`, which will keep `NaN` values.

```
data = df.pivot_table(values='value',
                        index=['Site', 'Storage', 'Commodity'],
                        columns='parameter', dropna=False).reset_index()
```